# If $\alpha$ be a multiple root of the order 3 of the equation $x⁴+bx²+cx+d=0$ then $α= 8d/3c​$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics, quartics

I found this statement online [here](https://brainly.in/question/42610130) and I think this statement is false.I would first  prove a general statement and then I would use it to find $\alpha$ in order to discard the statement given in online link.

**Theorem**:If the equation $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ has three equal roots, show that each of them is equal to $\frac{6c-ab}{3a^2-8b}$​

*Proof*;Three roots of the given equation are same hence, the roots can be assumed as $\alpha,\alpha,\alpha,\beta$

Here, $S_1=3α+β=−a;S_2
=3α(α+β)=b;S_3=α^2(α+3β)=−c;S_4=α^3β=d$

We need to evaluate the value of $\frac{6c-ab}{3a^2-8b}$​.

$6c−ab=α(3α^2−6αβ+3β^2)$

$3a^2−8b=3α^2−6αβ+3β^2$

Therefore,$\frac{6c-ab}{3a^2-8b}=\frac{α(3α^2−6αβ+3β^2)}{(3α^2−6αβ+3β^2)}=\alpha$

Now according to this ,putting $a=0$  we get $\alpha=\frac{-3c}{4b}$ which is not same as $\frac{8d}{3c}$ as claimed in online site.

My question is: Is the claim in online site wrong?or I have gone wrong somewhere in my proof.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If calculus is allowed, $0=f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=f''(\alpha)$ with $f'''(\alpha) \ne 0$.

Comment: I don't think it will reduce my calculations...what will be $\alpha$ finally?

Comment: @lone student I have edited my question in order remove any ambiguity...is it fine now?

Comment: @lone student nice appraoch and thanks for understanding,....further I request you to upvote my question as initially it was upvoted but later I saw downvote!

Comment: I expanded my answer for you.  I thought it would be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @lone student much appreciated...thanks a lot, initially there was a big misunderstanding between us but now you got my point and also in your expanded answer you cleared my doubt very beautifully!

Comment: Would you like me to examine the case where $a≠0?$

Comment: @lone student not needed,as that is already done in my answer,$\alpha=\frac{6c-ab}{3a^2-8b}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the roots be $\alpha, \alpha, \alpha, - 3\alpha$ so that their sum is $0$.

Now sum of products of 3 roots taken at a time is $$\alpha^3-3\alpha^3-3\alpha^3-3\alpha^3$$ and this must equal $-c$ and hence $\alpha^3=c/8$.

Now product of roots is $-3\alpha^4=d$ so that $\alpha^4=-d/3$ and hence $\alpha=(-d/3)/(c/8)=-8d/3c$.

Your question has thus a sign error. You can convince yourself by putting $\alpha=1$. The desired polynomial is $$(x-1)^3(x+3)=x^4-6x^2+8x-3$$ so that $c=8,d=-3$ and $-8d/3c=1=\alpha$.

---

I checked your approach and your theorem in question and its proof are correct. Thus $\alpha $ should equal $-3c/4b$.

Let's observe that sum of product of roots taken $2$ at a time is $$\alpha^2+\alpha^2+\alpha ^2-3\alpha ^2-3\alpha ^2-3\alpha^2$$ and this should equal $b$. Thus $b=-6\alpha^2$ and hence $$-\frac{3c}{4b}=-\frac{24\alpha^3}{(-24\alpha^2)}=\alpha$$ So we have $$\alpha=-\frac{3c}{4b}=-\frac{8d}{3c}$$

Comment: Great answer! +1. Just in case someone (like me) was wondering where the properties of the sums/products of the roots came from, I'll leave [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2920182/695196) to complement yours.

Comment: Nice answer @paramanand singh

Comment: @RobertLee: your linked answer is nice.

Comment: @Ibs: I updated my answer to give a feedback on your approach.

Comment: @Pramanand;good to see that but  **lone student** has done same thing before you could observe that.By the way thanks a lot in showing interest!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer looks correct to me.

We have,

$$(x-m)^3(x-n)=x^4+bx^2+cx+d=0.$$

$$x^4+bx^2+cx+d=x^4-x^3(3m+n)+x^2(3m^2+3mn)-x(m^3+3m^2n)+m^3n$$
$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}3m=-n \\3m(m+n)=b \\m^2(m+3n)=-c \\ m^3n=d \end{cases}
&\implies \begin{cases}-6m^2=b\\8m^3=c\end{cases}\\
&\implies \begin{cases}m=-\frac{3c}{4b},~b≠0\\ n=\frac{9c}{4b},~b≠0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

But, remember that there is a relationship between the coefficients.  This implies that the coefficients are not independent.  Therefore, to find the root we are looking for, we will use the coefficients that work for us.  However, both answers are absolutely correct.

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}3m=-n \\3m(m+n)=b \\m^2(m+3n)=-c \\ m^3n=d \end{cases}
&\implies \begin{cases}-3m^4=d\\8m^3=c\end{cases}\\
&\implies\begin{cases} m=-\frac{8d}{3c}\\ n=\frac{8d}{c}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

This means,

$$\begin{align}\frac{3c}{4b}&=\frac{8d}{3c}\\
\implies c^2&=\frac{32}{9}bd.\end{align}$$

Comment: [hdh](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4139459/460967/)

Answer (score 1):

**Verification of the Theorem**

Expanding
$$
(x-u)^3(x-v)=x^4\ \overbrace{-(3u+v)}^{\large a}x^3\ \overbrace{+3u(u+v)}^{\large b}x^2\ \overbrace{-u^2(u+3v)}^{\large c}x\overbrace{\ +u^3v\ \ }^{\large d}\tag1
$$
The first two derivatives are $0$ at $u$
$$
u^4+au^3+bu^2+cu+d=0\tag2
$$
$$
4u^3+3au^2+2bu+c=0\tag3
$$
$$
12u^2+6au+2b=0\tag4
$$
Substituting $v=d/u^3$ into $c+u^2(u+3v)=0$ gives
$$
u^4+cu+3d=0\tag5
$$
Writing $(2)$-$(5)$ as a matrix equation yields
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-\frac a4&\frac{3a^2-4b}{48}&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&a&b&c&d\\
0&4&3a&2b&c\\
0&0&12&6a&2b\\
1&0&0&c&3d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u^4\\u^3\\u^2\\u\\1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{6a}
\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\frac{3a^3-8ab}8&\frac{3a^2b-4b^2-6ac-48d}{24}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u^4\\u^3\\u^2\\u\\1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
Since $b^2+12d=3ac$, $\text{(6b)}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
u
&=\frac{3a^2b-4b^2-6ac-48d}{24ab-9a^3}\tag{7a}\\
&=\frac{3a^2b-18ac}{24ab-9a^3}\tag{7b}\\
&=\frac{ab-6c}{8b-3a^2}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$

---

**When $\boldsymbol{a=0}$**

Plugging $a=0$ into $\text{(7c)}$ gives
$$
u=-\frac{3c}{4b}\tag8
$$
If we use $a=0$, that is, $v=-3u$, we get $b=-6u^2$, $c=8u^3$, and $d=-3u^4$, we get not only that $u=-\frac{3c}{4b}$, as given in $(8)$, but also that
$$
u=-\frac{8d}{3c}\tag9
$$
which says that the problem in question is a factor of $-1$ off.

Comment: Wow!+1,it's really beautiful.